# How to check COM ports in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, com

Just like we can check COM ports in windows 7 or lower , by going to

> Control Panel >> Device Manager >> Ports

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv1pw.png]

How should we  check it in Windows 10?

Comment: By going to device manager?  What makes you think it changed?  You could do this in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1

Comment: It's in exactly the same place. Just checked. **Downvote: Little research effort.** (Darn, the assoc bonus is only 100)

Comment: @Ramhound: By seeing the change.

Comment: @mahmoodvics, The question is answered...

Comment: You can install currports tools and it gives all info including filtering and search https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html

Comment: Still not answered for me.  The ports do not show up even as hidden devices.  This may be a policy issue.

Comment: Definitely not there on my Windows 10.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same question and I found this page. And the answer is in @zipzit's comment. So I post it as answer here:

To see "Com Ports" in Device Manager in Windows 10 you should select "Show hidden devices" in View menu.

Comment: still not visible

Comment: @BlueClouds maybe it is shown as `Ports (COM & LPT)`

Comment: Nope, Ports not shown even after "Show hidden devices".

Comment: Same here, no Ports shown after "Show hidden devices".

Answer (score 5):

The Device Manager still exists in Windows 10 and should show this. It has not really changed at all between versions.

Open your `Start Menu` and just type in `Device Manager`, and it will come up.

[image]

Comment: Device manager is just fine.  But that's not the question.  Where are the COM ports called out?  I can't see them in Win10...    Oops... found them. Device manager has a thing "View Hidden Devices"  You have to specifically select that before the `Ports (COM & LPT)` are even visible.

Comment: The proper path to Device Manager is:
Open RESOURCE EXPLORER (Win+E), right click on THIS COMPUTER, click on DEVICE MANAGER

Anyway on my Windows 10 the number of each port is NOT shown here.

Comment: @jumpjack  Why do you think that is the "proper path"?  What about Win-R, devmgmt.msc ?

Comment: The win+R is a shortcut for advanced users  knowing what an executable is. A standard user "just clicks". :-)

Comment: Even easier is Win+x, m.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 21H2 and before @Mahmood Dehghan's answer, I had to go to Device Manager's "Advanced" menu and "add legacy hardware" for communication ports.  Then the View->"Show hidden devices" answer would work.