# Finding COM ports in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, com

This question is similar to [How to check Com ports in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1059447/how-to-check-com-ports-in-windows-10?answertab=active#tab-top)
I have run the device manager in administrator mode, and "show hidden devices" is checked. "Ports (COM & LPT)" still doesn't appear.

[image: device manager screenshot]

Comment: Most laptops do not have LPT and COM ports so why do you expect to see them?

Comment: I'm trying to install an old laser printer (QMS magicolor 3100) When installing and old printer by IP address it asks for a port (default is 1) the printer wants to be on port 35. My first attempt did not work so I removed the printer and was trying again. But even though I removed the printer, the install dialog said port 35 was already in use. I looked up ways to delete com port 35 so I could reuse it and found the instructions to go to the device manger and delete the port. Which I can't do because it com ports don't appear in the dialog as described.

Comment: @DavidPostill:  because plugging in a USB serial link in Windows makes a COMxx port appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1. Open Device Manager
2. Click on *Action*
3. Select *Add legacy hardware*
4. Click *Next*
5. Select *Install the hardware that I manually select from a list (Advanced)* and click *Next*
6. Scroll down and then select *Ports (COM & LPT)*, and click *Next*.
7. Select Manufacturer as per your need (the standard one or default option should work), and then click *Next*
8. Click *Finish*
9. Reboot

Comment: Went to control panel, right click on Device Manger to run as administrator, click on Action - only available option is "help". Tried again after clicking "show hidden devices" in view menu, same result.