# Why won't putty connect to usb serial port?

Tags: putty

I am using windows 7, 64bit I have a MKS gen l connected to a usb port The CH340 com port emulation driver converts USB in to a virtual com port, com 5, baudrate 115200. When I run putty I enter serial option change com1 to com5, change baudrate to 115200. Same settings as USB port emulator. Then I click open. An error code appears. `error code 2, cannot find specified file`. What file does it mean and where would it be ?

I have tried com port number change and baudrate change.

Comment: What driver did you use? Can you confirm said [com port exists](https://superuser.com/questions/1059447/how-to-check-com-ports-in-windows-10)?

Comment: The error message doesn’t necessarily refer to a file but more generally to a resource. Like the COM port. // Have you tried other serial terminal software yet? I can recommend Tera Term.

Comment: Yes. Com port exits through the chr340 driver.  Driver has been uninstalled and reinstalled.  The putty error says cannot find file.  What file does putty need ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532527/cant-connect-to-serial-port-using-putty

Comment: I've been using ardurino ide seriel monitor but putty seems easier to use. So I don't understand why it won't work.  The error code 2, is vague as to what is wrong

Comment: It seems like you did not read the linked SO site. You need to initiate the connection from the `Session` tab, not from the `Serial` tab.

Comment: I will try that.  TY